# Git merge using Beyond Compare when resolving merge conflicts caused by stash pop: files not found

Tags: git, merge, beyondcompare, mergetool

I am trying to unstash some files, one of the files causes merge conflicts, which I am trying to resolve using Beyond Compare. I am working on Windows 7.

Here's what I did:

- I applied the stash, which reported errors due to a merge conflict.
- I launched BeyondCompare using `git mergetool`
- My diff tool launched, but did not find these files
  `"*whatever*_LOCAL_21148.tex"` `"*whatever*_BASE_21148.tex"` etc. (and they actually don't exist either). But it
  creates three new files named `.merge_file_*some_hex_number*` which as far as
  I can see contain the base, local, and remote versions.

Can someone point me to what's going wrong here?

**My .gitconfig:**

```
[core]
    autocrlf = true
fileeditor
    eol = native
[user]
    name = David Wright
    email = 
[diff]
    tool = bc
    guitool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe /\"$LOCAL/\" /\"$REMOTE/\" "
    prompt = false
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc
[mergetool "meld"]
    cmd = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe /\"$LOCAL/\" /\"$BASE/\" /\"$REMOTE/\" --output=/\"$MERGED/\" --auto-merge
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    required = true
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
[http]
    sslVerify = false
[difftool "bc"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\BeyondCompare\\BCompare.exe
[mergetool "bc"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\BeyondCompare\\BCompare.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace bcompare.exe with bcomp.exe.

The executable bcomp.exe opens every diff and merge in a separate helper process, allowing version control to detect when the comparison is complete.

If you use bcompare.exe, all comparisons are opened in a single process. If bcompare.exe is already running when you launch a new comparison, the comparison is passed to the existing process and the new process exits. This causes version control to think the diff/merge is complete prematurely.

To configure Beyond Compare as the diff and merge tool for Git on Windows:

```
git config --global diff.tool bc
git config --global difftool.bc.path "c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe"
git config --global merge.tool bc
git config --global mergetool.bc.path "c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe"
```

The contents of .gitconfig after using the above commands:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc
[difftool "bc"]
    path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc
[mergetool "bc"]
    path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I changed the lines to what you suggested and tested the configuration. I don't know how that would solve the issue with git creating some weird file names `.merge_file_*some_hex_number*` instead of `*whatever*_LOCAL_21148.tex` though. I created a merge conflict and it seemed to work, but interestingly enough I was not able to replicate the issue... However, it seemed to work with your suggestion, but also my old `.gitconfig`.

Comment: I also saw that in some `.gitconfig` examples there is a section that contains `[merge] conflictstyle = diff3`, so I added this, however it seems to work with or without that now as well... I wonder if that might be a bug in git? The original error happened when another user made some changes in the same branch as I was working on and i stashed my changes, pulled his changes, and then popped the stash. I did create an "unstash" conflict but I was only able to create a conflict between two branches, not within the same branch, since I only have one user.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the weird filename issue, but I'm not an advanced git user. The [merge] conflictstyle setting looks like it only applies to non-interactive merges, I don't think it applies to interactive merges when git mergetool is used to launch an interactive merge.